# N-wave solution of conservation law $u_t + (u - u^2)_x = 0$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, hyperbolic-pde

How can we compute the "N-wave" source-solution of the conservation law
$$u_t + (u - u^2)_x = 0, $$
that is, the entropy solution of this conservation law with the initial data $u(0,\cdot) = (q -p) \delta$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac mass in $0$ and $0 <p, q$?

---

**Note:** For the case of the Burgers equation
$$u_t + (u^2)_x  = 0$$
the computation of N-wave solutions is in equation (2.1) of the paper

> *Liu, Tai-Ping; Pierre, Michel*, [**Source-solutions and asymptotic behavior in conservation laws**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-0396(84)90096-2), J. Differ. Equations 51, 419-441 (1984). [ZBL0545.35057](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0545.35057).

But I don't see how to extend this computation to the model above in the question.

Comment: You need to be careful about your notation.  Burger's equation should be written in the form $u_t + (u^2)_x = 0$.  What you have written is not this.  For the equation that you are asking about, do you mean $u_t - (u^2-u)_x = 0$?

Comment: @RobertBryant Thanks! Yes, I edited the question to avoid ambiguity in the equation